# Handling Item has already been added. Key in dictionary

Tags: .net, winforms, exception, dictionary

I was doing a project in visual studio, but when I want to open forms it gives me this awkward error:

> To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the
>   following errors must be resolved:
>   Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'help' Key being added: 'Help'

Why I'm seeing this problem and how can I solve it.

Comment: No idea how you got there, but somewhere something is doing Dictionary<String>.ContainsKey(String) Which is case sensitive and using the result as a go / no go on Dictionary<String>.Add(String) which isn't (sort of). So have a beaver through your code and make 'help' always 'help' or 'Help', then fix the underlying issue.

Comment: Are you usin g a case insensitive dictionary somewhere on `form_load`? `var caseInsensitiveDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>(
     StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);`

Comment: alright, I solved the problem it was from Resources.Designer.cs file which wasn't included in the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click on the Show All Files icon in Solution Explorer.  Open the Properties node, open Resources.resx, right click on Resources.Designer.cs and click on Include in project